# Pack 3 ints into short

Tags: java

I am trying to pack `3` `int`s into `short` and then get the values back; I am using a test code with the following values:

```
160, 71, 50
```

But when I try to *unpack* the values, ​​x & z are *wrong*, I get `15, 71, 50` (please, note `15` when `160` is expected).

**Why** is this? thanks. My code is

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] testValue = new int[]{160, 71, 50};

        short packed = pack(testValue[0], testValue[1], testValue[2]);

        int[] output = unpack(packed);

        System.out.println(output[0]);
        System.out.println(output[1]);
        System.out.println(output[2]);
    }

    public static short pack(int x, int y, int z) {
        return (short) (x << 12 | z << 8 | y);
    }

    public static int[] unpack(short packed) {
        int x = packed >> 12 & 0xF;
        int y = packed & 0xFF;
        int z = packed >> 8 & 0xF;

        return new int[]{x, y, z};
    }
```

Comment: you said you try to pack three `int`s into a `char`, but cast to `short`. A `short` has only half the bits of an `int`. Your question is thus unclear.

Comment: What is `index`?

Comment: `char` is **16-bit** value, when `160` is **8-bit**, `71` is **7-bit** and `50` is **6-bit**. So we need `8 + 7 + 6 == 21` bit to store these values, when we have just `16`

Comment: @iota i edited it.

Comment: You missed the `char` --> `short` in the first sentence of the question.

Comment: `pack()` returns a `short`, which is a signed 16-bit value. Given the shifting done inside `pack()`, the `x` value is 4-bit, `y` is 8-bit, and `z` is 4-bit, leaving supported value ranges as `x = 0-15, y = 0-255, z = 0-15`. Your `x` and `z` values **overflows** the supported ranges. You simply **cannot** pack those values into 16-bits like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's *impossible*; let's see why. We have `3` values to pack `160, 71, 50`:

```
 160 == 10100000 (binary), 8 bits long 
  71 ==  1000111 (binary), 7 bits long
  50 ==   110010 (binary), 6 bits long
```

Please, note, that

```
 160 is 8 bits long
  71 is 7 bits long
  50 is 6 bits long
 ------------------
       21 bits for all 3 numbers
```

we need at least **21** bits (`8 + 7 + 6`) to store all three numbers when `char` as well as `short` is **16** bit value only.

Comment: is there any other way to pack it? with int

Comment: @Lucas Lecce: `int` provides **32** bits which is enough and to spare assuming that all three numbers to pack are actually *bytes* (i.e. in `0..255` range). `int result = (a << 24) | (b << 16) | c;` reverse: `a = (result >> 24) & 0xFF; b = (result >> 16) & 0xFF; c = result & 0xFF;`

Comment: is that the numbers can vary, and there are numbers up to 1000, what can be done in that case?

Comment: @Lucas Lecce: you can still use **32-bit** integer (`int`). `1000 < 1024 = 10 bit`, so you want **30** bits to store all `3` numbers: `int result = (a << 30) | (b << 20) | c;` reverse: `a = (result >> 30) & 0x3FF; b = (result >> 20) & 0x3FF; c = result & 0x3FF;`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have enough bits in a 16 bit short to pack those three values.

Here is a breakdown of your bits:

```
160 << 12 = 0x0AA000
50  << 8  = 0x003200
71  << 0  = 0x000047
```

ORing these together results in:

```
0xA3247
```

Which can be stored in 3 bytes not two.
When casting to a short you end up with

```
0x3247
```

You could fit three values in the short if you could store each number in 5 bits individually.

Each number ranging from `0 - 31` for unsigned values. With only one value being able to take up 6 bits. This would yield `5 + 5 + 6 = 16` bits.